# pip feature to create a shell script[s] for a python package

Tags: pip

`poetry` has a feature for creating a shell script to set up the environment and launch the local python package.  The following directive in `pyproject.toml` generates a shell script `hercl` that has the needed env including python path/libraries to run the `hercl.hercl.py` `main()` :

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
hercl = "hercl.hercl:main"
```

I have heard rumors that `pip` itself has a similar capability. I have been unable to find that feature: does it really exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh! It looks like  `pip` supports `pyproject.toml` directly! It is called the [Build System Interface](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/build-system/) It is apparently a newer approach in conjunction with `setup.py`.  I'll get back here on how that goes.